# DKIM is failing with Microsoft emails as receivers , but is passing for non-Microsoft email receivers like Gmail

Tags: office365, dkim

I am sending an email from my Go Daddy domain with DKIM signature enabled. When I send this email to non-Microsoft emails like Gmail, DKIM validation shows as pass. But I send the same email to Microsoft 365 emails, DKIM validation shows as fail. Email header shows this, dkim=fail (signature syntax error).

Please find below the complete message details sent to my Microsoft email address (pprasanthk@kofaxpitchika.onmicrosoft.com) from my Go Daddy email address.
[text](https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/b1918ddd-0a53-4232-9f4c-4f0ba6467125?platform=QnA)

Could you please help me in identifying why is the DKIM validation failing for Microsoft 365 email addresses?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

--
Thanks
Prasanth

I tried to add other headers like Date, MIME-Version, and Message-Id, but still the DKIM signature validation is failing with Microsoft 365 email receiver with the error, dkim=fail (signature syntax error).